# django channels - delayed messaging does not work

Tags: django, django-channels

I am trying to imitate a time consuming django response, by delaying group message in Django channels, but it does not work.

The consumer is very simple:

```
class ExportConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    ...

    def delayed_message(self, event):
        print("In delayed")
        time.sleep(5)
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': 'delayed!'
        }))
    def immediate_message(self, event):
        print("In Immediate")
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': 'immediate_message!'
        }))
```

and in views I just send to a group two messages - for delayed and immediate processing:

```
class DecisionListView(PaginatedListView):
    ...

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
            async_to_sync(get_channel_layer().group_send)(
                '5e001793-18be-4a4b-8caf-c4a8144a11d2',
                {
                    'type': 'immediate_message',
                    'message': 'message'
                }
            )
            async_to_sync(get_channel_layer().group_send)(
                '5e001793-18be-4a4b-8caf-c4a8144a11d2',
                {
                    'type': 'delayed_message',
                    'message': 'message'
                }
            )
        return super().get(*args, **kwargs)
```

The 'immediate message' is delivered. And I get  `In delayed` on terminal (which means that it reaches the `delayed_message` but the message is never delivered (unless I comment out `time.sleep`.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE::
`AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer` does not work as well:

`consumers.py`:

```
class ExportConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    ...

    async def delayed_message(self, event):
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': 'whatever'
        }))
```

`views.py`:

```
class DecisionListView(PaginatedListView):
    ...
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _group_send = get_channel_layer().group_send
        _sync_group_send = async_to_sync(_group_send)
        _sync_group_send('5e001793-18be-4a4b-8caf-c4a8144a11d2',{"type":'delayed_message', 'message':'hello'})
        return super().get(*args, **kwargs)
```

UPDATE2:

The only thing that works for me is `asyncio.create_task`:

```
class ExportConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def delayed_task(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': 'LATER'
            }
        )

    async def delayed_message(self, event):
        asyncio.create_task(self.delayed_task())
        await self.send_json('NOW')

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        await self.send_json(message)
```

Comment: how do you import time ?

Comment: just `import time`. I should say that it exactly coincides with this tutorial on delayed tasks in Channels: https://github.com/jayhale/channels-examples-bg-task

Answer (score 0):

you should be using an `AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer` and async methods then you can use the sleep method from `asyncio`.

`time.sleep` will block your entire server.

-- unrelated
you should be sending `delayed.message` not `delayed_message` (channels replaces . with _ when calling functions)

Comment: no (see update). And the problem is not that the server is blocked - this action just is never executed.

Comment: in your consumer are you subscribing to the group `5e001793-18be-4a4b-8caf-c4a8144a11d2`